# Как сделать DateTimeFieldWithLabel неактивным reactjs bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, reactjs

Обычно элементы reactjs имеют атрибут `disabled` я задаю его и селектфилды и инпуты становятся серыми, пользователь не может их редактировать. В случае с `DateTimeFieldWithLabel` ситуация иная, `disabled` не помогает. Нашел [тут](https://github.com/quri/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker) API,но судя по ним можно лишь сделать `disabled` лишь на выбранные даты. 
Мне же нужно,чтобы весь пикер был `disabled`. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253606/react-bootstrap-readonly-input-within-formcontrol) я узнал,что есть атрибут `readOnly`,но он тоже не отработал. Есть ли какие-то варианты для реализации этого?

вот код:

```
const DateTimeFieldWithLabel = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var label = (this.props.label != null) ? this.props.label : "";
        var name = (this.props.name != null) ? this.props.name : "";
        var value = (this.props.value != null) ? this.props.value : "";
        return (
            <div className="datetimepicker input-group date ">
                <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
                <DateTimeField datetime={value}
                               name={name}
                               onChange={this.props.onChange}
                               readOnly={this.props.readOnly}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

И код использования данного элемента в рендере формы:

```
<div className="col-md-3 nopadding padding-right-xs">
                        <DateTimeFieldWithLabel label="Label"
                                                name='name'
                                                value={data.data}
                                                readOnly/>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Удалось заблокировать часть пикера:

```
<DateTimeField datetime={value}
                               name={name}
                               onChange={this.props.onChange}
                               inputProps={{disabled: this.props.readOnly}}
                />
```

Однако, по клику на иконку с календарем выбирается дата и подставляется в поле...как заблокировать его не знаю